# Forests mentioned in Hindu mythology

Tags: scripture, puranas

What are some of the major forests mentioned in Hindu mythology and what are their locations ?

I have researched and found out a few but want to know if there are more.

1. [Dandaka Aranya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandaka)
2. [Khandava Vana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khandava_Forest)
3. [Naimisha Aranya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naimisha_Forest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are Various forest’s mentioned in Hinduism Mythology as well as in Our Puranas and Itihasas like Mahabharata and Ramayana. Here are some of them -

**Tataka Forest** - from Valmiki Ramayana: -Valmiki Ramayana (Bala Kanda 26): Sri Rama killing Tataka:, **Chitrakoota Forest** - from Valmiki Ramayana: , **Madhuvana Forest** –Shreemad Bhagvatam , **Pushkara Forest** - from Padma Purana:  Vol 1  ,Shrushti Kanda Chapter 15 – Importance of dwelling at sacred places. **Kamyaka woods** – Mahabharata.

> तेन शब्देन वित्रस्ताः **ताटका वन** वासिनः |
>  ताटका च सुसंक्रुद्धा
>   तेन शब्देन मोहिता || १-२६-७
>
> By that sound the inhabitants of **Tataka forest** are startled, and
>   even Tataka is stupefied by that sound, and she is intolerably
>   infuriated at it. [1-26-7]
>
> विश्वामित्रः वचः श्रुत्वा हृष्टो दशरधात्मजः || १-२६-३४
>  उवास रजनीम्
>   तत्र ताटकाया वने सुखम् |
>
> On listening sage Vishvamitra's words, Dasharatha's son Rama,
>   comfortably stayed that night there in that forest of Tataka.
>   [1-26-34]
>
> [**Valmiki Ramayana (Bala Kanda 26**)](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga26/bala_26_frame.htm)

---

Sage Bharadwaja informs the route by which Rama and Lakshmana can reach **Chitrakuta**. They cross the River Yamuna by a raft prepared by themselves. Seetha prays the River Yamuna and a fig tree called Syama. The three of them traveled for a couple of miles along the bank of Yamuna, strolling in the charming forest and reach a leveled ground on the bank to take rest for the night.

> समासाद्य तु तम् वृक्षम् वसेद्वातिक्रमेत वा |
>  क्रोशमात्रम् ततो
>   गत्वा नीलम् द्रक्ष्यथ काननम् || २-५५-८
>  पलाशबदरीमिश्रम् रम्यम्
>   वंशैश्च यामुनैः |
>
> "Having approached that tree, you can stay there or go beyond it.
>   After going only for two miles from there, you will see a **beautiful
>   forest blue in colour** with bamboo trees touching upon Yamuna river
>   and interspersed with Sallaka and jujube trees." [**Valmiki Ramayana
>   ,Ayodhya Kanda**](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga55/ayodhya_55_frame.htm)

---

**Madhuvana Forest** -: Shreemad Bhagvat Purana [**SB 4.8**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/8): Dhruva Mahārāja Leaves Home for the Forest.

> तत्तात गच्छं भद्रं ते यमुनायस्तटम् शुचि|
>  पुण्यं **मधुवनं** यत्र
>   सांनिध्यं नित्यदा हरे: ||४२||
>
> tat tāta gaccha bhadraṁ te yamunāyās taṭaṁ śuci puṇyaṁ madhuvanaṁ
>   yatra sānnidhyaṁ nityadā hareḥ
>
> My dear boy, I therefore wish all good fortune for you. You should go
>   to the bank of the Yamunā, where there is a virtuous **forest named
>   Madhuvana,** and there be purified. Just by going there, one draws
>   nearer to the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who always lives
>   there.[**SB4.8.42**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/8/42)

---

**Pushkara Forest- Padma purana -:**
There is story of Lord Brahma in Padma Purana Vol 1  ,Shrushti Kanda Chapter 15 – Importance of dwelling at sacred places in which Pushkara Forest is described in detail.

> 20:  That lotus , that sprung from Vishnu’s naval , and in which I was
>   born , is called **Pushkkar Tirtha** by the sages who recite the
>   vedic-texts. 21 : When Brahma was thus thinking, this idea came to his
>   mind: 'I now go to the earth.
>
> 22-24. Reaching the place first, he
>   entered that best forest, full of many trees and creepers; adorned
>   with many flowers; filled with the notes of many birds; crowded with
>   groups of many beasts; making gods and demons fragrant with the
>   perfumes of the abundant flowers of trees; its ground was graced with
>   flowers which were as it were intentionally placed there.
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> ---

There is mentioning of " **Daruka forest**" , in   Koti Rudra Samhita of Shiva Purana  where 12 Jyotirlingas are described  in chapter "Dwadash Jyotirlinga Mahatmya". -:

> परल्यां वैद्यनाथं च डाकिन्यां भीमाशंकरम् ।
>   सेतुबंधे तु रामेशं नागेशं **दारुकावने** ॥२॥
>
> Paralyam Vaidyanatham Ca Dakinyam Bhimashankaram | Setubandhe Tu
>   Ramesham Nagesham **Darukavane** ||2||

---

We also find two forest names in  [**Mahabharata index**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01003.htm)   Part 22 -   namely - **Dwaita** & **Kamyaka**

> The entrance of the sons of Pandu into the **romantic Dwaita wood**;
>   conversation of Bhima, Yudhishthira, and Draupadi; the coming of Vyasa
>   to the Pandavas and his endowing Yudhishthira with the power of
>   Pratismriti; then, after the departure of Vyasa, the removal of the
>   Pandavas to the **forest of Kamyaka;**

Comment: Chitrakuta is a mountain. Not a forest.